# Preservation of inequality on continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $ f,g:M \subset \mathbb{R}^{p} \to \mathbb{R} $ countinuous function at $a \in M$. Show that if $f(a) < g(a)$ then exists $ \delta >0 $ such as for $x$ and $y$ in $M \cap B(a, \delta) $ implies $ f(x) < g(y) $.

Demonstration:

Since $f, g$ are continuous, then for all $ \epsilon > 0 $ we can find two sets such as:

$ A = f^{-1}(B(f(a), \epsilon_1) $; and
$ B = g^{-1}(B(g(a), \epsilon_2) $.

Therefore $ A = B(a,\delta_1) $ and $ B = B(a, \delta_2) $.

Taking $ \epsilon = max (\epsilon_1 , \epsilon_2) $ we can find a $ \delta $ such, as if $ C = B(a,\delta) $ for $ \delta = max (\delta_1,\delta_2) $

Said that we can find a neighboorhood around $f(a)$ and $g(a)$, and we can pick two points called $ x', y' $ such as $ f(x') < g(y') $, since  $f, g$ is continuous locally we can find:

$ x \in M \cup B ( a, \delta_1 ) $ such as $ f^{-1}(x') = x $, we also can do the same to $ y $, since we can find a $ g^{-1}(y') = y \in M \cap M B(a,\delta_2) $. That said we can get the $ max(\delta_1, \delta_2) $ that satisfies both conditions at same time.

My questions are: It's correct? Is it the correct approach? Can I be more objective (I think that I'm very vague and verbose). Any improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't say that $f^{-1}(B(f(a),\epsilon_1)) = B(a,\delta_1)$. Inverse image of balls need not be balls. However, your result is true for metric spaces in general, as in:

> **Proposition:** Let $f,g: (M,{\rm d}) \to \Bbb R$ be continous maps in $a \in M$, with
>   $f(a) \leq g(a)$. Then exists an open ball $B$ with center $a$ such
>   that $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x \in B$.

**Proof:** Given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ (taking the minimum of the $\delta$s for $f$ and $g$) such that for $x \in B(a,\delta)$ we have: $$\begin{matrix}
f(a)-\epsilon < f(x) < f(a) + \epsilon \\ g(a) - \epsilon < g(x) < g(a) + \epsilon
\end{matrix} \implies \begin{matrix}
-f(a)-\epsilon < -f(x) < -f(a) + \epsilon \\ g(a) - \epsilon < g(x) < g(a) + \epsilon
\end{matrix},$$ and $g(x) - f(x) > g(a)-f(a) - 2\epsilon$. Take the $\delta$ corresponding to $\epsilon = (g(a)-f(a))/2$, and we get the result.

Comment: Yes. I'm in metric spaces, the absence of this statement is just because I don't know how to work in other spaces (I'm stil on real analysis). But thank you for the clarification.

Comment: You might like "Espaços Métricos e Introdução à Topologia", from Hygino Domingues. The only rule that changes in this game is that you can't do operations with elements in the function's domain. This will still be possible in normed vector spaces, though.